# How can I upgrade to version 3.0 as a user?

Tags: upgrades

I am an end user and see there is a 3.0 version. Can I upgrade for free and what steps do I need to take to do that?

Comment: What do you mean "end user"? Are you not a developer? Do you not have full admin access?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade instructions are found [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html), although i wouldn't recommend it as an end user. You want to backup your database in case something goes wrong, change file paths/content, etc. Even if you have the access and knowledge to run the scripts, you should have a developer do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a support article here worth reading that discusses the things you should consider before updating to Craft 3, especially if you are an end user.

https://craftcms.com/support/should-we-update-to-craft-3